# Why my code doesn't work in grok debugger

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm new to this site and I'm starting to learn how to use logstash, Grok Debugger return : Compile error for this log line:

```
[29/02/2020 07:34:27.805] - sc879537 - 10.107.192.25 - 12 - Transaction 2659 COMPLETED 6849 ms wait time 3597
```

Here's my code :

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => ["\[%{LOGDATE:logdate}\] \- %{USERNAME:user} \- %{IP:clientip} \- %{NUMBER} \- %{WORD} %{NUMBER:exectime} %{WORD} %{WORD} %{WORD} %{NUMBER:waittime}"]
  }
}
  
date {
    match => [ "logdate", "MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: hello and welcome to SO. Please avoid using generic titles, and try to use titles that explain and summarize the question instead. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62536835/edit) your title.

Comment: What does *can't parse* mean?

Comment: sorry, my english isn't verry good, I've changed to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below the grok pattern that will match your log pattern.

```
\[%{DATESTAMP:logdate}\] \- %{USERNAME:user} \- %{IPV4:clientip} \- %{NUMBER} \- %{WORD} %{NUMBER:exectime} %{WORD} %{NUMBER:time} %{GREEDYDATA:data} %{NUMBER:waittime}
```

I have used the [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to verify the grok pattern. Please find below the output of the grok pattern.

[image]
[image]